# How can I make the review queue skip questions with tags on my ignore list?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I'm reviewing possible-duplicate [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) posts.

Irritatingly questions from my ignored tags from my user preferences (currently just [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) and [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask)) also show up.

Is it possible to filter them out? `-django` and `not django` in the tag filter don't work as they would in the question search bar.

If not, I suggest that it should be.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. Afaik the ignored tags have nothing to do with the review queue. In the review queue you are able to select the tags you want to review but you can't exclude any other tags. +1 I support your idea.

Comment: @mehow How do you select the tags you want to review?

Comment: @LuisMendo when you are in the review queue [click the "filter"](http://s28.postimg.org/gz1kc04x9/Untitled.png) and set your filters there

Comment: I could've sworn I've seen this asked before (I wholeheartedly agree that we need this)

Comment: Please implement this. To expand on this suggestion, the review queues desperately need filtering of all kinds. You have no idea how often I click Skip in close because I'm not familiar with the subject.